# how the rises up and down button is made?

Tags: css, layout, button, navigation, navigationcontroller

In the website below website's layout in the navigation,when hovered on the buttons it rises up and when the mouse is taken away it sinks down,how to do it either in css or other ways ?

www.bigfishgames.com/

Comment: I wouldnt be able to view the site, but, ofen its as simple as mouseover/mouseout and changing the dark/light lines over, so if initially its light top and left, and dark right and bottom, change them over, and it appears to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with plain CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { border-radius: 4px; width: 100px; height: 20px; background: green; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; text-align: center; padding: 10px 0px; }
div:hover { top: 40px; padding-bottom: 20px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>Howdy</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how both `padding-bottom` and `height` are changed to give the illusion that the `div` is expanding 'upwards'.

Comment: Can u discuss it more broadly please ?

Comment: Give me half-an-hour, gotta go out!